# How to enable cipher suites starting with both TLS_ and SSL_?

Tags: ssl

We purchased and correctly installed a certificate for our domain. We checked it with several tools, like this one:

https://cryptoreport.websecurity.symantec.com/checker/views/certCheck.jsp

Everything seems fine and the site works great with https.

We need to use a payment gateway in Spain that is requiring us to enable at least one of the following cipher suites:

- SSL_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_MD5
- SSL_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA
- SSL_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA
- SSL_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
- SSL_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA
- SSL_RSA_FIPS_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA

Without any of those enabled, there is no way to get notifications  when the payment process is finished.

According to the results provided by [the symantec websecurity check](https://cryptoreport.websecurity.symantec.com/checker/views/certCheck.jsp) Our server has enabled the cipher suite TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, which is similar to SSL_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA but starting with TLS_ instead of SSL_.

The questions I have are:

- What is the difference between TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA and SSL_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA?
- Is there any way I could enable both of them?

The website is hosted in a plesk server with centos 7 and is using apache as the web server. I tried to enable SSLv3 and SSLv2 protocols, even disable TLS, but I could never enable any SSL_* cipher suites at all.

Thanks!

Comment: TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA and SSL_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA are exactly the same ciphers. Don't let you confuse by the prefix. Similar TLS and SSL are just different names for the basic technology where TLS is the new name and SSL the old one. TLS 1.0 is actually SSL 3.1 at the protocol level and TLS 1.0 has more in common with SSL 3.0 than SSL 3.0 has in common with SSL 2.0.

Comment: Ok, I understand is the same cipher. Thanks!. Is it possible to enable both of them in apache somehow?

Comment: I don't understand your question. It is the same cipher with code 0x00,0x2F. There is no "both", there are only different names for the same single cipher. And Apache uses yet another name, i.e. the OpenSSL syntax where this cipher is called AES128-SHA.

Comment: ...I guess my question does not make sense because I didn't really understand what I was asking. Now it's clear. They requesting me to enable certain ciphers, which apparently I already have. The thing is that I'm using the wrong name. When they connect to my server, they check for the cipher SSL_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA. Since I'm using the other name (TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA) they just refuse to connect. I think that is the problem. So, is there a way I can choose which name to use?

Comment: The name is not used at all on the wire. The server has the cipher with code 0x002F configured. This cipher is known under various names but when they use some client to connect to the server the name does not matter, only the code. I have no idea how exactly they check and what you have configured and if the problem is that they don't understand what they are doing or if  something else is the case.  It impossible to tell from the information so far.

Comment: I have a standard plesk server with a standard apache web server with no special configuration. The certificate is correctly configured and working. I have used several tools to check that. Furthermore, the cipher suite they require is enabled, according to your comments. I will try to find out why they are requesting me to use a particular name for the  0x002F cipher suite, something that makes no sense to me now after your last comment. Thanks a lot for your help!